# Recurrent sequence and arithmetic mean sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Find the limit$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n}{S_n},
$$ where the sequence $(x_n)$ is defined by$$
x_1=1\quad \text{and}\quad x_{n+1}=\frac{1+x_n}{\sqrt{n+1}},\quad\forall n\ge 1
$$and $$
S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}},\quad\forall n\ge 1
$$
From the first terms of sequence I deduce that this one is an decreasing sequence. Then, I know that $S_n$ has the same magnitude as $2\sqrt{n}$, the sequence of arithmetic means of the terms of the sequence $x_n$ has the same magnitude as the sequence itself. So, the limit that I have to compute becomes$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n}x_n}{2}.
$$
That's all I can deduce. How can I go farther? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $S_n\to\infty$ monotonically, by [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) it's enough to compute
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1}+x_n)-(x_1+\cdots+x_{n-1})}{S_n-S_{n-1}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt nx_n$$
We have
$$\sqrt{(n+1)!}x_{n+1}=\sqrt{n!}+\sqrt{n!}x_n$$
from which
\begin{align}
\sqrt{n!}x_n-1
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\sqrt{(k+1)!}x_{k+1}-\sqrt{k!}x_k)\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{k!}
\end{align}
from which
\begin{align}
\sqrt nx_n
&=\frac 1{\sqrt{(n-1)!}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{k!}
\end{align}
By applying Stolz–Cesàro theorem again, we get
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt nx_n
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\sqrt{n!}-\sqrt{(n-1)!}}\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac 1{\sqrt n}}\\
&= 1
\end{align}